# Add key with default value to nested clojure hashmap

Tags: recursion, clojure, hashmap, clojurescript

I tried to do Clojure but stuck with the nested hashmap.
I have a structure like this:

```
{:type "view" 
 children: [
     {:type "view" 
      :id "123"} 
     {:type "view" 
      :children [
         {:type "view"}]}]}
```

Now I want to add field `:id` to each hashmap with random string if not exist. To get something like this:

```
{:type "view" 
 :id "43434"
 children: [
     {:type "view" 
      :id "123"} 
     {:type "view" 
      :id "456"
      :children [
         {:type "view"
          :id "5656"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `clojure.walk/postwalk` to do this:

```
 (walk/postwalk
  (fn [v]
    (if (and (map? v) (nil? (:id v)))
      (assoc v :id (str (rand-int 9999)))
      v))
   data)
=>
{:type "view"
 :id "3086"
 :children [{:type "view"
             :id "123"}
            {:type "view"
             :id "8243"
             :children [{:type "view" :id "3222"}]}]}
```

...where `data` is your input map. `postwalk` is traversing your nested maps, and `assoc`iating an `:id` key (a random integer string) on every map that doesn't have one.

Comment: nice solution, but notice that if the input data has another maps (not just `:children`, but also for example `:attributes`), they would also have ids assigned recursively, since this variant doesn't care about the semantics of data,  but rather modifies every map. Still, if the data structure isn't a subject to some future changes, it is ok.

Comment: Using `(and (map? v) (nil? (:id v)) (= (:type v) "view"))` probably addresses @leetwinski's concerns

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the `walk` variant there are some more:

the simplest solution would be the recursive update

```
(defn upd [{:keys [id children] :as data}]
  (assoc data
         :id (if id
               id
               (str (rand-int Integer/MAX_VALUE)))
         :children (mapv upd children)))
#'user/upd

user> (upd data)
;;=> {:type "view", 
;;    :children [{:type "view", :id "123", :children []} 
;;               {:type "view", 
;;                :children [{:type "view", :id "35223257", 
;;                            :children []}], 
;;                :id "551012526"}], 
;;    :id "1899442274"}
```

you can also use clojure's zippers for that:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(loop [curr (z/zipper map? :children (fn [n ch] (assoc n :children (vec ch))) data)]
  (if (z/end? curr)
    (z/root curr)
    (recur (z/next
            (let [node (z/node curr)]
              (if (:id node)
                curr
                (z/replace curr
                           (assoc node :id
                                  (str "id-" (rand-int Integer/MAX_VALUE))))))))))

;;=> {:type "view", 
;;    :children [{:type "view", :id "123"} 
;;               {:type "view", 
;;                :children [{:type "view", :id "id-92807721"}], 
;;                :id "id-1357268462"}], 
;;    :id "id-803083206"}
```